# Variadic Functions in NASM Win64 Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, variadic

Simple variadic function implementation in NASM Assembly. When implemented like I have below:

**sum.asm**

```
;; bits 64
default rel

extern printf

section .text
    global main
    global sum
main:
    sub     rsp, 40
    mov     r9d, 3
    mov     r8d, 2
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ecx, 3
    call    sum
    lea     rcx, [fmt]
    mov     edx, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 40
    ret
sum:
    sub     rsp, 24
    test    ecx, ecx
    mov     qword [rsp+28H], rdx
    lea     rdx, [rsp+28H]
    mov     qword [rsp+30H], r8
    mov     qword [rsp+38H], r9
    mov     qword [rsp+8H], rdx
    jle     .end
    lea     eax, [rcx-1H]
    lea     rcx, [rsp+rax*8+30H]
    xor     eax, eax
.recurse:
    add     eax, dword [rdx]
    add     rdx, 8
    cmp     rdx, rcx
    jnz     .recurse
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.end:
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 24
    ret

%macro str 2
    %2: db %1, 0
%endmacro

section .rdata
    str "%d", fmt
```

We can change how many variables are being given to the function without having to change the amount of memory being allocated to the function itself.

```
main:
    sub     rsp, 72
    mov     dword [rsp+30H], 6
    mov     dword [rsp+28H], 5
    mov     dword [rsp+20H], 4
    mov     r9d, 3
    mov     r8d, 2
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ecx, 6
    call    sum
    lea     rcx, [fmt]
    mov     edx, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 72
    ret
```

There are no comments in the code since what I'm doing should be pretty self-explanatory. Any advice and all topical comments on optimizing the code and its performance, as well as standard conventions, is appreciated!

Compiled as follows using `VS2017 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`:

> ```
> > nasm -g -f win64 sum.asm
>
> > cl /Zi sum.obj msvcrt.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov     qword [rsp+8H], rdx
> ```

Why would you store this value at all? You never use the stored value afterwards!

You can easily dismiss all of the local storage for the *sum* routine. No need for `sub rsp, 24` nor `add rsp, 24` instructions. Also, why 24 bytes when all you use are the middle 8 bytes? The same happens in *main* where you reserve 40 bytes when all you use are the middle 24 bytes! The alternative *main* evens wastes 24 bytes this way.

You can avoid the separate *.end* code by clearing the accumulator very early and jumping to the one `RET` you really need.

> ```
> lea     eax, [rcx-1H]
> lea     rcx, [rsp+rax*8+30H]
> ```

You can calculate this upper limit in just one instruction. Absorb the decrement by 1 operation into the displacement of the `LEA`:

```
lea     rcx, [rsp + rcx*8 + 28h]
```

And since by the time of this calculation the `RDX` register already points at `[rsp + 28h]` you could simply write:

```
lea     rcx, [rdx + rcx*8]
```

---

Applying these changes:

```
sum:
    xor     eax, eax
    test    ecx, ecx
    jle     .end
    mov     [rsp + 10h], rdx    ; 1st arg for sure (ECX=1+)
    mov     [rsp + 18h], r8     ; maybe 2nd arg
    mov     [rsp + 20h], r9     ; maybe 3rd arg
    lea     rdx, [rsp + 10h]    ; lower limit
    lea     rcx, [rdx + rcx*8]  ; upper limit
.more:
    add     eax, dword [rdx]
    add     rdx, 8
    cmp     rdx, rcx
    jb      .more
.end:
    ret
```

When comparing memory addresses like in your code `cmp rdx, rcx`, it would be best to not check for equality but rather for excess. Provided the step is non-zero, checking for the 'below' condition will happen eventually while checking for the 'equal' condition might never happen at all (if there's an error in the program of course...).

---

An even simpler solution uses the `ECX` register as a counter (like it was on input):

```
sum:
    xor     eax, eax
    test    ecx, ecx
    jle     .end
    mov     [rsp + 10h], rdx    ; 1st arg for sure (ECX=1+)
    mov     [rsp + 18h], r8     ; maybe 2nd arg
    mov     [rsp + 20h], r9     ; maybe 3rd arg
    lea     rdx, [rsp + 10h]    ; lower limit
.more:
    add     eax, dword [rdx]
    add     rdx, 8
    sub     ecx, 1
    jnz     .more
.end:
    ret
```

---

> We can change how many variables are being given to the function without having to change the amount of memory being allocated to the function itself.

True, but the caller still has to reserve - somewhat mysteriously - those 24 bytes that correspond to the 3 arguments passed via registers `EDX`, `R8D`, and `R9D`.
I think it would be simpler to either pass **all** values on the stack or pass a pointer (in `RDX`) to a buffer holding all of those values. In both cases the count remains in `ECX`.
Next code combines it all:

```
    sub     rsp, 48
    mov     rdx, rsp
    mov     dword [rdx + 40], 6
    mov     dword [rdx + 32], 5
    mov     dword [rdx + 24], 4
    mov     dword [rdx + 16], 3
    mov     dword [rdx + 8], 2
    mov     dword [rdx], 1
    mov     ecx, 6
    call    sum
    ...

sum:
    xor     eax, eax
    test    ecx, ecx
    jle     .end
.more:
    add     eax, dword [rdx]
    add     rdx, 8
    sub     ecx, 1
    jnz     .more
.end:
    ret
```